# Pygame problem user_input appear always in the next iteration

Tags: python, pygame

In fact, I am a new software student who jsut finished his python class. I am learning myself how to work with pygame. In fact, I am trying to implement a math game which proposes random math equations to solve and wait the users input before moving to the next equation. In my case, each time I write my answer (it appears in the next iteration of the while loop with another math equation (not the original question). I partly understand why this is happening but I am not really able to solve the problem

Here is my code for the moment, some elements are still missing though

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import operations
import re

# Constants
SKYBLUE = (152, 195, 195)
BEIGE = (210, 190, 150)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 204)
KEYBOARD_NUMBERS = [pygame.K_0, pygame.K_1, pygame.K_2, pygame.K_3, pygame.K_4, pygame.K_5,
                    pygame.K_6, pygame.K_7, pygame.K_8, pygame.K_9, pygame.K_MINUS]

# Globals
final_state = False
start_the_game = False
choose_level = False
start_playing = False

user_answer = ''
color = BEIGE
equations_list = []
answers_list = []
score = 0


class Operations:

    def __init__(self, x, y, operation, name):
        font = pygame.font.Font('font/Pixeltype.ttf', 60)
        self.surface = font.render(operation, False, (64, 64, 64))
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.name = name

    def draw(self, color=BEIGE):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, self.rect.center, 50)
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)


class Levels:
    def __init__(self, x, y, niveau, name):
        font = pygame.font.Font('font/Pixeltype.ttf', 60)
        self.surface = font.render(name, False, (64, 64, 64))
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.niveau = niveau
        self.name = name

    def draw(self, color=BEIGE):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, self.rect.center, 50)
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)


class Display_Operation:
    def __init__(self, operation=None):
        font = pygame.font.Font('font/Pixeltype.ttf', 40)
        self.operation_surf = font.render(f'{operation}', False, (64, 64, 64))
        self.rect = self.operation_surf.get_rect(topleft=(50, 130))
        self.rect.h += 5

    def draw(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, BEIGE, self.rect)
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, BEIGE, self.rect, 10)
        screen.blit(self.operation_surf, self.rect)


def display_operation(details_list):
    if details_list[0] == 'Addition':
        return operations.addition(details_list[1])
    elif details_list[0] == 'Substraction':
        return operations.substraction(details_list[1])
    elif details_list[0] == 'Multiplication':
        return operations.multiplication(details_list[1])
    else:
        return operations.division(details_list[1])


def correct_answer(math_equation, answer):
    math_equation = math_equation.replace('=', '')
    num1, num2 = re.split(r'[+\-x/]', math_equation)
    if '+' in math_equation:
        return int(num1) + int(num2) == int(answer)
    elif '-' in math_equation:
        return int(num1) - int(num2) == int(answer)
    elif 'x' in math_equation:
        return int(num1) * int(num2) == int(answer)
    else:
        return int(num1) / int(num2) == int(answer)


def image_surface(image):
    return pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()


def image_rect(image_surf, x, y):
    return image_surf.get_rect(center=(x, y))


def phrase_rect(sentence, x, y, color=(64, 64, 64)):
    global text_font
    surf = text_font.render(sentence, False, color)
    rect = surf.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    return (surf, rect)


def events_loop():
    global start_the_game, choose_level, start_playing, user_answer, final_state, num
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if start_the_game:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                operationes = [addition, substracction, multiplication, division]
                for op in operationes:
                    if op.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        choose_level = True
                        game_algo.append(op.name)
                if choose_level:
                    levelos = [level_1, level_2, level_3]
                    for level in levelos:
                        if level.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                            start_playing = True
                            game_algo.append(level.niveau)

            if start_playing:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        user_answer = user_answer[:-1]

                    else:
                        user_answer += event.unicode
        elif final_state:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    num = 0
                    final_state = False
                    start_the_game = False
                    choose_level = False
                    start_playing = False


        else:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    start_the_game = True


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Little Professor')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Images
little_professor_surf = image_surface('Graphics/start_screen_little_professo.png')
little_professor_surf = pygame.transform.smoothscale_by(little_professor_surf, 0.4)
little_professor_rect = image_rect(little_professor_surf, 300, 200)

# Font
text_font = pygame.font.Font('font/Pixeltype.ttf', 50)
# Game title
title_surf, title_rect = phrase_rect('Little Professor', 300, 60)
# start message
start_message_surf, start_message_rect = phrase_rect('Press space to start', 300, 350)

# Operations
sentence_surf, sentence_rect = phrase_rect('Choose a Mathematical Operation: ', 300, 50)

addition = Operations(80, 200, '+', 'Addition')
substracction = Operations(230, 200, '-', 'Substraction')
multiplication = Operations(380, 200, 'x', 'Multiplication')
division = Operations(530, 200, '/', 'Division')

command_surf, command_rect = phrase_rect('Put your mouse on the operation', 300, 300)
command1_surf, command1_rect = phrase_rect('and press space ', 300, 330)

# Levels:
level_surf, level_rect = phrase_rect('Select a level: ', 300, 50)
level_1 = Levels(150, 200, 1, '1')
level_2 = Levels(300, 200, 2, '2')
level_3 = Levels(450, 200, 3, '3')

# Operation to use in game
game_algo = []

# Game In Playing
play_surface = text_font.render('Let\'s Play !', False, (64, 64, 64))
play_surface_rect = play_surface.get_rect(topleft=(50, 50))
user_rect = Display_Operation().rect
user_rect.x = 180
user_rect.y = 200
user_rect.w = Display_Operation().rect.w + 5
answer_prompt_surf = text_font.render('Answer: ', False, (64, 64, 64))
answer_prompt_rect = answer_prompt_surf.get_rect(topleft=(50, 200))

click_surf, click_rect = phrase_rect('Press Enter to continue ', 230, 300)

# Final State
score_surf, score_rect = phrase_rect(f'Your score: {score} out of 10', 300, 100)
restart_surf, restart_rect = phrase_rect('Press Space to play again', 300, 200)
mathgame_surf = image_surface('Graphics/mathgame.webp')
mathgame_surf = pygame.transform.smoothscale_by(mathgame_surf, 0.05)
mathgame_rect = image_rect(mathgame_surf, 300, 300)

num = 0
while True:
    # for loop
    events_loop()
    # Game screen
    # Operations Screen
    if num == 10:
        start_the_game = False
        final_state = True
    else:
        pass
    if start_the_game:
        screen.fill(SKYBLUE)
        screen.blit(sentence_surf, sentence_rect)
        addition.draw()
        substracction.draw()
        multiplication.draw()
        division.draw()
        screen.blit(command_surf, command_rect)
        screen.blit(command1_surf, command1_rect)
        # Levels screen
        if choose_level:
            pygame.time.wait(300)
            screen.fill(SKYBLUE)
            screen.blit(level_surf, level_rect)
            level_1.draw()
            level_2.draw()
            level_3.draw()
            screen.blit(command_surf, command_rect)
            screen.blit(command1_surf, command1_rect)
        # Real Game Screen
        if start_playing:
            screen.fill(SKYBLUE)
            screen.blit(play_surface, play_surface_rect)
            screen.blit(answer_prompt_surf, answer_prompt_rect)
            screen.blit(click_surf, click_rect)

            user_rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, user_rect)
            user_text_surf = text_font.render(user_answer, True, (64, 64, 64))
            user_rect.w = max(Display_Operation().rect.w, user_text_surf.get_width() + 10)
            screen.blit(user_text_surf, user_rect)

            equation = display_operation(game_algo)
            question_surf = Display_Operation(equation).operation_surf
            question_rect = Display_Operation(equation).rect
            screen.blit(question_surf, question_rect)

            equations_list.append(equation)

            while True:
                event = pygame.event.poll()
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()

                if num == 0 and start_playing:
                    num += 1
                    break

                else:
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                            if user_answer.strip().replace('-', '').isdigit():
                                x = user_answer
                                answers_list.append(x)
                                print(equation, x)
                                user_answer = ''
                                num += 1
                                break  # Exit the inner loop when the user presses enter

                        elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                            user_answer = user_answer[:-1]
                        else:
                            user_answer += event.unicode
                            user_rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, user_rect)
                            user_text_surf = text_font.render(user_answer, True, (64, 64, 64))
                            user_rect.w = max(Display_Operation().rect.w, user_text_surf.get_width() + 10)
                            screen.blit(user_text_surf, user_rect)

    elif final_state:
        screen.fill(YELLOW)
        screen.blit(score_surf, score_rect)
        screen.blit(restart_surf, restart_rect)
        screen.blit(mathgame_surf, mathgame_rect)
    # Starting screen
    else:
        screen.fill(YELLOW)
        screen.blit(little_professor_surf, little_professor_rect)
        screen.blit(title_surf, title_rect)
        screen.blit(start_message_surf, start_message_rect)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

If anyone can help me solving this issue I would really appreciate it

Comment: Welcome @Aladinco . :) Could you limit your code preview to the most relevant parts? Currently, you force the reader to go through your whole code, which will scare a lot of people willing to help. Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

The main issue in your game is that the player's answer and the new question are not updating smoothly in the game loop. Right now, when a player enters their answer, it only shows up in the next loop iteration, along with a new question. This can be confusing for the player.

To fix this, you need to do three things:

Handle Inputs and Updates Separately: Split your game loop into two parts. One part should handle player inputs (like typing the answer), and the other should update the game state (like checking the answer and generating a new question).

Immediate Feedback: As soon as the player presses Enter, you should process their answer, update the display to show that answer, and then generate the next question. This way, the player sees their input immediately, and the game feels more responsive.

Streamline Game States: Make sure your game efficiently transitions between different states (like answering a question and moving to the next) without unnecessary delays.

In essence, it's about making the game react more quickly to player inputs and ensuring that the game's responses (like showing the answer and bringing up the next question) are immediate and seamless.

In simpler terms, think of it like this: One part of your loop is the game's ears and hands – listening for what the player does and updating things accordingly. The other part is the brain – thinking about what to do next, like generating new questions. And throughout this, the game needs to keep showing the player what's going on, without waiting.

I hope that makes it clearer! If you need more help with the specific code to do this, just let me know!

Comment: Can you give me some indications on where I should do the modifications ( is it in the nested while True ) . It’s 1 am in my country now so I am gonna go sleep now and work again on this tomorrow hoping to solve this problem !! Small code snippets would be appreciated